# How do I move multiple <style> nodes content to single <style> node efficiently

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have several `<style>` tags with css across the document and I would like to collect their css and move it to the single `<style data-ssr-styles="head">`

I'm currently doing this

```
const collectedCss = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[data-ssr-styles='chunk']"))
    .reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr.innerHTML], [])
    .join('');
document.querySelector("[data-ssr-styles='head']").appendChild(document.createTextNode(collectedCss));
```

I suppose getting styles via `innerHtml`/`innerText` is not how they intended be processed - **what is the correct / efficient way to move styles from one node to another**? Should I iterate over text nodes and append them to the main style instead?

```js
const collectedCss = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll("[data-ssr-styles='chunk']")
  )
  .reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr.innerHTML], [])
  .join("");

document
  .querySelector("[data-ssr-styles='head']")
  .appendChild(document.createTextNode(collectedCss));
```

```html
<style data-ssr-styles="head"></style>

<style data-ssr-styles="chunk">
  body {
    background: red;
  }
</style>
<style data-ssr-styles="chunk">
  body {
    background: blue;
  }
</style>
<style data-ssr-styles="chunk">
  body {
    background: green;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: why do you vote for closing without commenting? I described as precisely as I could - ask in comments what needs to be clarified. even snippet is there